# Mcrypt PHP - Module Initialization Failed

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, php-extension, mcrypt

### How to install the mcrypt modules on PHP?

I need to install the mcrypt extension on WAMPServer so that I can use IDEA encryption on passwords. I can't use any other type of encryption, because the large database I am interacting with already uses IDEA encryption on passwords.

I have done quite a bit of research on installing the mcrypt extension on PHP. I saw that there were 2 main steps:

1. Install the extension
2. Refer to the directory where the algorithms and modes are located in the php.ini file

Step 1 I have managed to complete successfully as it no longer gives the fatal error: "Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt..."

Step 2 is where I am having issues, because now when I call the mcrypt_encrypt function php returns the warning: "Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Module initialization failed..."

- I downloaded the mcrypt extension from: http://www.dlldll.com/php_mcrypt.dll_download.html
- I downloaded the mcrypt algorithms and modes from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/Production/libmcrypt-2.5.7.tar.gz/download

I placed the directory with all the algorithms and modes (libmcrypt) in the  php extensions folder  and then in php.ini I wrote these 2 lines:

`mcrypt.algorithms_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/libmcrypt/modules/algorithms"`

mcrypt.modes_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/libmcrypt/modules/modes"

I then restarted WAMPServer and it gave the warning: "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_mcrypt.dll' - The specified module could not be found."

I have been searching all over the web for tutorials on how to install the mcrypt extension and I can't find any! So I came to good old StackOverflow in hopes that someone might be able to help?

Comment: I don't have a libmcrypt.dll file... Do you mean the php_mcrypt.dll, or am I missing something?

Comment: It still isn't working! I downloaded that file and placed it in the apache bin directory and in the php5.4.3 directory. I then updated the php.ini to point to this location... And it still gives me the same error!! `phpinfo` says that mcrypt is enabled... Do you have any other suggestions, maybe a tutorial on this?

Comment: Actually, it is working now... Just not with IDEA encryption! Do you know a download link for IDEA?

Comment: I have restarted Apache 3 times now and `print_r(mcrypt_list_algorithms());` returns `Array ( [0] => cast-128 [1] => gost [2] => rijndael-128 [3] => twofish [4] => cast-256 [5] => loki97 [6] => rijndael-192 [7] => saferplus [8] => wake [9] => blowfish-compat [10] => des [11] => rijndael-256 [12] => serpent [13] => xtea [14] => blowfish [15] => enigma [16] => rc2 [17] => tripledes [18] => arcfour )` No IDEA listed...

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1:**

`libmcrypt.dll` isn't available to Apache/`php_mcrypt.dll`.  Guess we should have checked `phpinfo()` first! *mcrypt is available*

**Suggestion 2:**

`print_r(mcrypt_list_algorithms());` should show IDEA algorithm... since it's not a free algorithm (although the [patent expired in May/2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758713/what-are-the-terms-of-use-for-mcrypt-idea-in-php)) it may not be included .. *IDEA algorithm isn't listed as available*

**Suggestion 3:**

You're not going to enjoy this, but all I'm reading suggests you have to [build PHP yourself](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) (well [first `mcrypt`](http://objectmix.com/php/479405-%5Bphp%5D-mcrypt-dont-work.html) with IDEA, then `php` with MCRYPT) which on Windows will be a bit of a pain (not having all the default compilers etc built in like Linux).  As an alternative you could look around for a windows PHP binary version that *includes* MCRYPT/IDEA.. looks like some of them include it (an old version, a [64 bit version](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-3-5-x64-64-bit-for-windows/), a VC9 version).  *Unfortunately* people have ideas in install guides/discussions about it so it's tricky to find documentation as to whether the `IDEA` algorithm is included ;)